# Inline If statement not working

Tags: visualforce, inline, if

Inline if not working with inputfield...using two properties from the controller...**compiler error**: Syntax error. Missing ')'

```
<apex:inputField id="inpModelValue" value="
    {!IF(wrap.strdealerbaseparameter=='Retail',objPWDUT.AI_R0_Retail__c,
      IF(wrap.strdealerbaseparameter=='Delivery',objPWDUT.AI_R0_Delivery__c,
      IF(wrap.strdealerbaseparameter=='Booking',objPWDUT.AI_R0_Booking__c,
      IF(wrap.strdealerbaseparameter=='TestDrive',objPWDUT.AI_R0_Test_Drive__c,
      IF(wrap.strdealerbaseparameter=='Lead',objPWDUT.AI_R0_Lead__c,
      IF(wrap.strdealerbaseparameter=='QualifiedLead',objPWDUT.AI_R0_Qualified_Lead__c,
      objPWDUT.AI_R0_Retail__c))))))}"/>
```

Much Appreciated for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would use a [`CASE`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) instead of `IF`in this *case* since you are always checking the same field value `wrap.strdealerbaseparameter`.

I think that function below is more readable than what you have written.

```
{!CASE(wrap.strdealerbaseparameter,
      'Retail', objPWDUT.AI_R0_Retail__c,
      'Delivery', objPWDUT.AI_R0_Delivery__c,
      'Booking', objPWDUT.AI_R0_Booking__c,
      'TestDrive', objPWDUT.AI_R0_Test_Drive__c,
      'Lead', objPWDUT.AI_R0_Lead__c,
      'QualifiedLead', objPWDUT.AI_R0_Qualified_Lead__c,
       objPWDUT.AI_R0_Retail__c)}"
```

However, you can't use "static" binding in any other type of formula, so you have to be willing to use "dynamic" binding instead. Here's what that looks like:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!objPWDUT[CASE(wrap.strdealerbaseparameter,
      'Retail','AI_R0_Retail__c',
      'Delivery','AI_R0_Delivery__c',
      'Booking', 'AI_R0_Booking__c',
      'TestDrive', 'AI_R0_Test_Drive__c',
      'Lead', 'AI_R0_Lead__c',
      'QualifiedLead', 'AI_R0_Qualified_Lead__c',
       'AI_R0_Retail__c')]}" />
```

The `[]` syntax in Visualforce allows you to specify a string (even as the result of a formula evaluation) to determine which field to render/bind to, thus being "dynamic." You'll get runtime exceptions if the field name is misspelled or not queried in the original query.

---

See below for prior version:

However, this won't solve your problem as you can't have this sort of "dynamic binding" in the `value` attribute of `apex:inputField` (AFAIK).

What you *can* do is render different `apex:inputField` based on the the value of the `wrap.strdealerbaseparameter` property. Something like below:

```
<apex:inputField render="{!wrap.strdealerbaseparameter=='Retail'}" value="{!objPWDUT.AI_R0_Retail__c}"/>
<apex:inputField render="{!wrap.strdealerbaseparameter=='Delivery'}" value="{!objPWDUT.AI_R0_Delivery__c}"/>
<apex:inputField render="{!wrap.strdealerbaseparameter=='Booking'}" value="{!objPWDUT.AI_R0_Booking__c}"/>
<!-- etc. -->
```

That's the best I can come up with at the moment. Maybe someone else will have a better solution.

Comment: +1 smukov, you were close. It's actually possible to choose the field at runtime, and I've provided an example. The rest of the answer was spot-on, though.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox, that's a great solution. I love this community! You can learn so much here and everybody is nice and respectful. Thank you again for teaching me something new today.

Comment: And we love helping people! I made another small adjustment, I had the `{!` in the wrong place. But I did test this in my developer org before I added the edit, so it definitely works.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for the solution...it worked and I learnt something new!